# HMVC Integration in Codeigniter view paths

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I am trying to intregrate HMVC to codeigniter. I have installed the MX files to thrid_party and uploaded the MY_Loader , MY_Loader and MY_Model to the application/core folder. it is working fine

I have two issues

1) How to add the module routes that overide the application routes

I am accessing module through the link `localhost/domain/admin/portfolio`

I have tried adding routes.php to the modules config `application/modules/portfolio/config/routes.php` with below details

```
 $route['admin/portfolio'] = 'portfolio/admin/portfolio';
 $route['admin/portfolio/add'] = 'portfolio/admin/portfolio/edit';
 $route['admin/portfolio/edit/(:num)'] = 'portfolio/admin/portfolio/edit/$1';
```

On my root application config  already added a routes

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/login';
```

Because of this route 'admin/login' in the `application/config/routes.php` it is showing page not found. To fix this I have currently added the ``` module/portfolio/config/routes`` above the 'admin/login'. Is there any other method  instead of adding it to the ```application/config/routes`.

2) How to access the module view files
I have controller accessing the view files from `application/controlles/admin/`

```
    $this->load->view('admin/view_header',$data);
    $this->load->view('admin/view_portfolio',$data);
    $this->load->view('admin/view_footer');
```

Comment: How are you authorising access to, what appears to be, an Admin Function?

Comment: I have updated my answer in regards to your modules::run command.

Answer (score 1):

You have placed your Portfolio Controller under

```
application/modules/portfolio/controllers/admin
```

which is fine.

Your route (which will hit the index by default) should be

`$route['admin/portfolio'] = 'portfolio/admin/portfolio';`

**Aside: other naming considerations**

What I tend to do is to create a controller with admin in the name...

So I would have **PortfolioAdmin.php** or something along those lines, so I know by the file name, it's admin "Stuff", when I am playing with it in my Editor/IDE.

**UPDATE**:
In regards to your

```
Nor this works Modules::run('admin/portfolio', $data);
```

So you would then use the full controller name... Do not use routes, they are for URLs. Any module you want to call from another module you always use the full name.

```
Modules::run('portfolio/admin/portfolio', $data);
```

Comment: I have updated the content. it is still not working. i have copied module location is it correct